# Python week number generating

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to generate the number of the week based on the date that user input. I am aware of this following function that will give me the specific week number for the date that i input.

```
datetime.date(2012,5,21).isocalendar()[1]
```

my problem is that i want to make the week 1 of my year to start in April 1st instead of Jan 1st. Which means, my calendar for every year starts from April 1 and ends at march 31. Not Jan 1 to dec 31. Is there any build in function i can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

```
from datetime import date
end = date(2012, 5, 21)
start = date(2012, 4, 1)
Diff = end - start      
print Diff.days / 7     # convert to number of weeks
```

Comment: actually i was looking for a shorter answer but what you provided does the trick as well.. but i think that the result of diff.days/7 need to be added by 1 as (/) in python will give you an integer.So, it won't show the correct week number unless we add it by 1.